# Storm - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I have deployed storm server, but I am receiving the following error every time I start supervisor.

```
2014-09-08 09:04:40 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-09-08 09:04:40 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [WARN] Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350) ~[zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5-1392090]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068) ~[zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5-1392090]
```

can anyone please help me with the error.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Starting Zookeeper was my issue here:

```
zkServer start
```

After which you should rerun the topology.

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup Zookeeper? Zookeeper should be up and running before running storm topologies.

In the [storm](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html) documentation  refer to **Set up a Zookeeper cluster** section.

Answer (score 0):

This exception has one meaning only: nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. Either that was wrong or you didn't start the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Zookeeper Installation directory.
2. cd to bin.
3. Give the command `./zkServer stop` in all zookeeper nodes.
4. Again give the command `./zkServer start` in all zookeeper nodes.
5. Start all the storm processes(Nimbus and Supervisor).

Now you will not get this exception in Zookeeper cluster.